# append the next frames into video when use MediaEncoder in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, mp4

I'm trying to make a video that consists of the RenderTextures.

I've written this from Unity Documentation,
but I want to append the next RenderTextures after I make a video.

- Make encoder, AudioBuf as a member variable -> It leads to error that cannot create the .mp4 file or crashed on Editor.

Is there any method to keep the current .mp4 file handler for appending other RenderTextures after this function ends?

```
    void EncodeVideoFromPredistortedImages(RenderTexture[] predistortedImages) {
    // Compose the video again to encode from the Images list.    
    Texture2D convertedToTex2d = new Texture2D(predistortedImages[0].width, predistortedImages[0].height);
    videoAttr.width = (uint)convertedToTex2d.width;
    videoAttr.height = (uint)convertedToTex2d.height;

    using (var encoder = new MediaEncoder(encodedVideoFilePath, videoAttr/*, audioAttr*/))
    using (var audioBuf = new Unity.Collections.NativeArray<float>(sampleFramesPerVideoFrame, Unity.Collections.Allocator.Temp)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < predistortedImages.Length; ++i) {
        Debug.Log($"Current encoding idx {i} of {ExtractedTexturesArr.Length}");        

        RenderTexture prevRT = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = predistortedImages[i];
        convertedToTex2d.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, predistortedImages[i].width, predistortedImages[i].height), 0, 0);
        convertedToTex2d.Apply();
        RenderTexture.active = prevRT;

        encoder.AddFrame(convertedToTex2d);
        encoder.AddSamples(audioBuf);
      }
      encoder.Dispose();
      DestroyImmediate(convertedToTex2d);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I use `OpenCV.Videos` to deal with this problem instead of using unity 3rd party VideoWriter due to performance.